# Which is better for a slow computer and a user who is only familiar with Windows, Ubuntu or Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, windows-7

I have Windows 7 and my computer has become very slow over the years. I am looking into switching over to Ubuntu or possibly Lubuntu. I was hoping to get some advice. I enjoy playing computer games and searching the web quickly, but right now my computer starts up incredibly slow and takes a while to open programs. I have never used a Linux OS as my main OS so I need a good transition between Windows and Linux. Which is better for this Lubuntu or Ubuntu?

Also, I want a way that I can switch over to Ubuntu/Lubuntu, but have the option to easily switch back if I decide that I do not like it. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for your advice!

Edit: I also see that Xubuntu is an option for faster gaming performance. Could this be an even better option?

Comment: I'd prefer Xubuntu — with low requirements it still supports transparent windows which is nice. Also, since you didn't mention your hardware: I have Kubuntu *(yeah, KDE)* on my old notebook with GPU intel GM965, CPU Celeron 1.86. GHz, RAM 2 Gb. It is in use by my gf, and runs fine despite a bunch of effects I enabled like transparency, desktop cube, wobbling windows… The system as it boots takes just ≈600Mb RAM.

Comment: Also for better game performance you could run games in separate XServer — like `xinit /absolute/path/to/app -- :1 vt8` would run the app where you could switch with keys «Ctrl+Alt+F8», and back «Ctrl+Alt+F7». Note though — servers on switches being suspended, so if you're playing in network game, disconnect is possible. Though I'm usually playing like this Xonotic, and everything is okay — you just need to do the switch quickly.

Comment: @Hi-Angel seriously? He didn't even install Linux and you're already giving him commands? Prefer graphical ways for beginners. Always.

Comment: @EduardoCola there's no way to run separate XServer with purely graphical way. They asked for performance in game, that's the best way I think *(at least with XServer — I don't know Wayland/Mir specifics)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple answer**: in your case, Lubuntu. Its interface is pretty similar to Windows' (unlike the vanilla Ubuntu) and it's very lightweight.

**Actual answer**: none. If you enjoy Windows' user-friendly ways but want performance at the same time:

- Ubuntu is very user-friendly and "out-of-the-box", but is a bit too resource consuming;
- Lubuntu is extremely lightweight and smooth, but it lacks some essential user-friendly features. It's not focused on beauty, so do not expect **any** eye-candy or beautiful details. Its configuration is somewhat hard and you'll have to do complex tasks to reach simple objectives. For example, if you want to create a keyboard shortcut you'll have to manually edit scripts or get third-party software from the internet (you could do the same task with 2-3 clicks in Ubuntu).

Long story short, if you want something smooth, with high performance and at the same time beautiful, full-featured and user-friendly, stick with **Xubuntu**. It comes with the Xfce Desktop Environment. It's so amazing it managed to give new life to my 10 years old fighter and still kept amazingly beautiful.

If you compare its performance to Lubuntu's, the change rate is somewhat around 0. Both systems (with 32-bit i386 architecture) use about 180 MB of RAM when idle, and stay at 0-1% of CPU usage.

Xubuntu is also extremely customizable, so you can make it look (and feel) whatever you want.

That's my recommendation for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I am feeling like I will most definitely go with Xubuntu. Do you know of the easiest way to try Xubuntu, but keep Windows so that I can switch back just in case? I have never tried to switch my OS and am not sure if there is a simple way to do this.

Comment: First, download Xubuntu's ISO (I recommend 14.04 LTS) from http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/ . Choose you architecture (32- or 64-bit) and get it through HTTP or torrent.

Follow one of the tons of installation guides around the web to make a Xubuntu Live Media (the instructions are pretty much the same for any Ubuntu flavor, so you can search for 'how to install Ubuntu'). You'll need a DVD OR a USB drive. From the Live media you'll be able to test Xubuntu without making any modifications to your machine.

Comment: When you start Xubuntu's installer there will be an option "Install alongside Windows" (or whatever system you already have in your machine). Check this option and Xubuntu will make 2 partitions for itself: one for the root filesystem (/) and another swap partition (which is used to reduce RAM memory stress and hibernate). Nothing from Windows will be deleted/removed/touched. The installation should take about 20 minutes. Read carefully all the instructions from official documentations (specially if you are using EFI systems).

Answer (score 2):

By the way your question is asked, I assume you already read a bit about the different Ubuntu derivatives:

Yes, Lubuntu is more resource and memory friendly because of its desktop environment, LXDE. It works especially well on older computers with lesser performance. Since you have not posted your hardware however, it is difficult to say what impact the OS change could have. I don't think Lubuntu and Xubuntu make much of a difference performance-wise. They both look relatively similar to a Windows system.

If you are mainly playing games, think of this: Most games, especially older titles are developed specifically for Windows. While some newer titles are also developed for Linux systems and distributed via Steam OS/Linux, most games are still only available for Windows. Similar to an Xbox game that can not simply be started on a Playstation, you will probably have to install compatibility software, such as Wine/Play on Linux or CrossOver.

While a lot of games can be played this way, there is a chance you will run into problems sooner or later. The safest way would be to set up a dual OS system with a Windows partition for games and Ubuntu for everything else or you make an Ubuntu Live USB drive on your Windows system with Pendrivelinux and try everything out before switching completely.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know if I could keep a dual OS system for an extended period of time? Is it safe to have this and with this setup up can I switch back and forth easily? Maybe I could use Xubuntu for general use then switch back to Windows 7 to play certain games.

Comment: Also, I have a HP Pavilion DV6 with Intel Core i7-3610QM @ 2.3 GHz processor, 8GB ram, and an Nvidia GEFORCE GT 650M 1GB graphics card. And this laptop is about 4 years old.

Comment: Yes, you are able to switch between both systems by rebooting. Install Windows first and leave enough space for Ubuntu on the hard drive upon installation. After Windows is installed, start an Ubuntu DVD/USB drive and select the option to keep Windows and install it next to it on the drive, it will then automatically install and configure a boot menu with which you can select the system to start at each boot.

The hardware you posted is much newer than I expected. You could also run the regular Ubuntu! Because of your Nvidia GPU I would suggest Lubuntu over Xubuntu, as there may be a few bugs.